# plotly r xaxis date show all months

Tags: r, plotly

Please help. I want to show ALL months in my xaxis ticks. I've tried adding dtick=1 but they're clumping on one side. I can't change size of the graph since I will embed this in rmarkdown.

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = c("2016-08-01", "2016-09-01", "2016-10-01", 
                       "2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01",
                      "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01",
                      "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01",
                      "2017-08-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-10-01",
                      "2017-11-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01"), index = 1:18, y = 90000)
plot_ly(data=df, x=~x, y=~y, type="bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode="group", xaxis=list(type="date", tickformat="%b %Y", tickangle=-90))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding tickvals

```
library(plotly)
tickvals = c("2016-08-01", "2016-09-01", "2016-10-01", 
             "2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01",
             "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01",
             "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01",
             "2017-08-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-10-01",
             "2017-11-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01")
df <- data.frame(x = tickvals, index = 1:18, y = 90000)
plot_ly(data=df, x=~x, y=~y, type="bar") %>% 
  layout(barmode="group", xaxis=list(type="date", tickformat="%b %Y", tickangle=-90, tickvals=tickvals))
```